# prevent autocomplete in chrome address bar

Tags: google-chrome

IS there a way to prevent automatic autocomplete in the Chrome address bar? If I start typing an address and an autocomplete suggestion appears it overrides my original typing.  Is there an option to make the user hit Tab or another key to actually select it? I would still like autocomplete to appear, but not select it by default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to totally prevent autocomplete in the omnibar. You might already be aware, but you can just press `backspace` or `delete` to remove the suggested text. And pressing `enter` will accept the suggestion. This is probably the best way and is simple enough for most.

Answer (score -1):

To do that.

1. Go to settings. (hamburge menu on top right corner)
2. Then navigate to advanced settings.
3. In the privacy section uncheck the box of **Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar**. And you are done.

Also the autocomletion depends on your search history. So making it clear will also help you.

Comment: No, this does not resolve the issue.  Previously navigated addresses are the issue, not predicted searches.

Comment: Have you tried Clearing history of chrome? Ctrl+shift+delete.